# What is the python equivalent to a Java .jar file?

Tags: python

Java has the concept of packaging all of the code into a file called a Jar file.  Does Python have an equivalent idea?  If so, what is it?  How do I package the files?

Comment: Python doesn't have an exact equivalent to .jar files. What exactly do you want to do? Are you trying to distribute a single module, a package directory, or two or more of the above? Do you want it to be installed, or used in-place? Do you want to disallow, allow, or require configuration on the target machine?

Comment: Usually, the answer to what you want to do is to create a packaging distribution. See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org) for details.

Comment: [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) is a version of Python which runs on the Java Virtual Machine... so this is not what you are asking for, but I think it's worth noting that you can certainly package up a bunch of Jython scripts into an actual JAR file if you want to.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Python doesn't have any exact equivalent to a `.jar` file.

There are many differences, and without knowing exactly what you want to do, it's hard to explain how to do it. But the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org) does a pretty good job of explaining just about everything relevant.

Here are some of the major differences.

---

A .jar file is a compiled collection of classes that can be dropped into your application, or installed anywhere on your `CLASSPATH`.

In Python:

- A `.py` (or `.pyc`) module can be dropped into your application, or installed anywhere on your `sys.path`, and it can be imported and used.
- A directory full of modules can be treated the same way; it becomes a package (or, if it doesn't contain an `__init__.py`, it merges with other directories of the same name elsewhere on `sys.path` into a single package).
- A `.zip` archive containing any number of modules and packages can be stored anywhere, and its path added to your `sys.path` (e.g., at runtime or via `PYTHONPATH`) and all of its contents become importable.

---

Most commonly, you want things to be installed into a system, user, or virtualenv `site-packages` directory. The recommended way to do that is to create a `pip`-compatible package distribution; people then install it (and possibly automatically download it from PyPI or a private repo) via `pip`.

`pip` does a lot more than that, however. It also allows you to manage dependencies between packages. So ideally, instead of listing a bunch of prereqs that someone has to go download and install manually, you just make them dependencies, and someone just has to `pip install your-library`. And it keeps track of the state of your site-packages, so you can uninstall or upgrade a package without having to track down the specific files.

---

Meanwhile, in Java, most `.jar` files are cross-platform; build once, run anywhere. A few packages have JNI native code and can't be used this way, but it's not the norm.

In Python, many packages have C extensions that have to be compiled for each platform, and even pure-Python packages often need to do some install-time configuration. And meanwhile, "compiling" pure Python doesn't do anything that can't be done just as well at runtime. So in Python, you generally distribute *source* packages, not *compiled* packages.

However, `.wheel` is a binary package format. You can `pip wheel` to build binary packages for different targets from the source package; then, if someone tries to `pip install` your package, if there's a wheel for his system, that will be downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 7):

[Easy Install from `setup_tools`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#id8) defines the `.egg` format for deploying Python libraries or applications. While similar to JAR, it is nowhere spread as universally as JARs in Java world. Many people just deploy the `.py` files.

A newer format, intended to supersede eggs, is [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel).

Comment: This is a pretty out-of-date answer; you shouldn't be recommending deprecated tools to people.

Comment: @AlexanderGessler: `easy_install` is deprecated. See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org).

Comment: @AlexanderGessler: Without knowing what specifically he wants to do, there is no real answer here. Neither `.egg` nor `.wheel` is really like `.jar` in some of the most important ways (especially if you have any native code and/or platform-specific configuration).

Answer (score 7):

Though it's not a perfect susbstitute of jar due to portability issues, I would add the "auto-extracting" archive way.

One possibility is "makeself": https://makeself.io/

But if you don't need to package external files, and if you like KISS approach, the following is a nice and clean alternative:

The following is taken from Asim Jalis's [website](https://gist.github.com/asimjalis/4237534).

## How to deploy a Python application as a zip file

Create a file `__main__.py` containing:

```
print "Hello world from Python"
```

Zip up the Python files (in this case just this one file) into `app.zip` by typing:

```
zip app.zip *
```

The next step adds a *shebang* to the zip file and saves it as `app`—at this point the file `app` is a zip file containing all your Python sources.

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' | cat - app.zip > app
chmod 755 app
```

That’s it. The file `app` is now have a zipped Python application that is ready to deploy as a single file.

You can run `app` either using a Python interpreter as:

```
python app
```

Or you can run it directly from the command line:

```
./app
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/asimjalis/4237534