# Python Pytest files to convert single executable file and executed via batch file

Tags: python, pytest, pyinstaller, exe

I have 10 pytest files and the demand is to convert these to a single executable file, The project contains properties file in which data is present.I need the data for pytest as in the console I was running via python -m pytest but in pyinstaller it is asking for a single .py file to be converted. I tried but came into no solution. Please help me its important. Even though I convert to a single executable the exe file never runs.

In Java I used to create a jar file and it can be processed via .bat file and it reads data from properties file and it works
If in python something like that we can achieve will be welcomed

Comment: Create one more file which will import tests from the other 10 files and try to compile that one file?

Comment: Actually the problem is that even though I did that also. By running pyinstalled to convert it into single file it is showing missing modules in the in the text file and no .exe file is created

Comment: Or refer------   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455978/what-is-the-python-equivalent-to-a-java-jar-file